# Creating a 'slide-in' menu using js and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the moment I'm creating my navigation which will consist of several icons and when you click on each one a slide in menu will appear. So far this is the javascript and css i've tried. Unfortunately nothing seems to happen when I click on my icons.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Explore Canterbury</title>

 <style>

.infoIcon {
  background-image:url(img/information.png);
  width:34px;
  height:34px;
  display: block;
}
}
    </style>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/my-js.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Static navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><span class="LocIcon nav-toggle"></span></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

          <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            </div>
          </form>

        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

      <div class="information-menu">
        <h1>Explore Canterbury</h1> 
        <p>Welcome to our website, please look around!</p>        
      </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

css

```
.information-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
  text-align: left;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.information-menu.open{
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

javascript

```
$(function(){

    $('.nav-toggle').on('click', fuction(){
        $('.information-menu').toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like that wihtout using css-transitions:

```
    $(function(){

    $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function(){
        $('.information-menu').slideDown(600);
    });
});
```

to slide in form the side start with `width: 0px;`

```
    $(function(){

    $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function(){
      $(".information-menu").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
    });
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L7L1eb04/1/

Comment: I want it to slide in from the left, what do I change slideDown to?

Comment: Start with width: 0px; and do it like this: `$(".information-menu").animate({width:'toggle'},350);`

Comment: also, get this console error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'

Comment: give me a second i'll fiddle it

Comment: now getting this error my-js.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: i works in jsfiddle. this error comes up when you didnt include jQuery or included it wrong. make sure you  have this line: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: thank you, i think i included it in the wrong place!

Comment: just out of curiosity, what part of this code determines the width of the final menu?

Comment: In your CSS: width: xxpx; in the .information-menu :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is just a typo in the code.

Trying changing the following line:

```
$('.nav-toggle').on('click', fuction(){
```

to

```
$('.nav-toggle').on('click', function(){
```

I didn't test your complete code, but a snippet seemed to work as expected.

**UPDATE:**

In response to OP comment, the original code, with the typo corrected, is shown below. It appears to work as expected. Run the code snippet and click on "Click Me!" to try.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('.information-menu').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.information-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}
.information-menu.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><span class="LocIcon nav-toggle">Click Me!</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </nav>

</div>

<div class="information-menu">
  <h1>Explore Canterbury</h1> 
  <p>Welcome to our website, please look around!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ahh yes, whoops! still doesn't seem to be working for me though